# Is there a library for TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, ssl, python-2.6

I've got an assignment to create a socket server and client that communicate securely. I have to use either TLS 1.1 or 1.2 to avoid BEAST attacks. We're given Python version 2.6, but this doesn't have support for TLS 1.1 or 1.2.

Are there any external libraries you guys know of that implement this in Python 2.6, or would I be better off using the Python 3.4 dev version that added support?

Comment: You seem to be able to use TLS/SSL in 2.6, take a look at the [ssl](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html) module.

Comment: @SamvanKampen: I'm pretty sure 2.6's module only handles TLSv1.0, not 1.1, which is why the OP is asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert: oh, I didn't even realize, sorry.

Comment: The `ssl` module was either originally maintained separately on PyPI, or had a backport; I forget which. A quick search to see if there's a newer version available for 2.6 might be worth doing. As another option, there are definitely third-party wrappers around OpenSSL intended to provide more functionality than the stock `ssl` module, like `ssl4py` and `pyOpenSSL`, but I don't know much about any of them.

Comment: As a side note, if using Python 3 is a realistic option, I'd suggest that anyway. Whether I'd use 3.4, or 3.3 with something like `pyOpenSSL`, would depend on how my schedule fits in with the [Python 3.4 release schedule](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0429/) and how reliable/long-term-supportable/etc. I needed my release to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick test, if you build [`pyOpenSSL`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL) on top of OpenSSL 1.0.1, it looks like you get TLSv1.1 and 1.2 support. And it supports Python 2.6+/3.2+.

The API is different from the stock `ssl` module, but the [`Connection`](http://pythonhosted.org/pyOpenSSL/openssl-connection.html) object is not that different from `ssl.SSLSocket`, so there's a good chance porting will just be a trivial search-and-replace.

With the current released version 0.13.1, there is implicit TLS 1.1 and 1.2 support, but no way to explicitly request or require them. The best you can do from the client side is set `SSLv23_METHOD` add `OP_NO_SSLv2` and `OP_NO_SSLv3` options, which guarantees TLS 1.0, 1.1, or 1.2. I haven't tested what you can do from the server side.

With the trunk code (the patch in [#1020632](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/1020632) has been committed), there is explicit 1.1 and 1.2 support. From the client side, you can use `TLSv1_1_METHOD` to get TLSv1.1 only, `TLSv1_2_METHOD` to get TLSv1.2 only, and probably (I haven't tested) `SSLv23_METHOD` with `OP_NO_SSLv2`, `OP_NO_SSLv3`, and `OP_NO_TLSv1` to get 1.1 or 1.2. Again, I haven't tested what you can do from the server side.

You should be able to `pip install bzr+lp:pyopenssl` to install the trunk; if not, check it out or download a current tarball and `pip install` that.

---

My guess is that you can write code that always gets 1.2 when using properly-built pyOpenSSL 0.13.1 and OpenSSL 1.0.0 or later, but may silently use something worse if either the client or server environment is built in a way that doesn't meet those requirements, and have no way to detect the problem. If you want the connection to fail instead of fall back in that case (which you probably do), it looks like you'll need a newer pyOpenSSL.

---

Here's my first test on a mostly-clean OS X 10.8.5 machine with Homebrew and `pip` installed:

```
$ brew install --universal openssl
$ sudo LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include pip-2.6 install pyOpenSSL
$ python2.6
>>> import socket, OpenSSL
>>> OpenSSL.SSL.SSLeay_version(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLEAY_VERSION)
'OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013'
>>> ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
>>> sock = socket.socket()
>>> ssock = OpenSSL.SSL.Connection(ctx, sock)
>>> ssock.connect_ex(('www.ssllabs.com', 443))
0
>>> ssock.send('GET /ssltest/viewMyClient.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.ssllabs.com\r\n\r\n')
66
>>> ssock.recv(16384)
-- snipped headers for chunked reply
>>> ssock.recv(16384)
'2000\r\n'
>>> d = ssock.recv(16384)
>>> d.find('TLS 1.1')
2324
>>> d.find('TLS 1.0')
2432
>>> d[2324:2432]
'TLS 1.1</td>\r\n\t\t<td class="tableRight">Yes</td>\t\t\t\r\n\t</tr>\r\n\t<tr class="tableRow">\r\n\t\t<td class="tableLeft">'
```

This proves (assuming ssltest.org is correct) that we not only claim TLS 1.1 support, but also made a 1.2 or 1.1 connection.

Comment: Cool, I'm looking into this. At first glance I don't see anything about TLS 1.1 or 1.2, but I'll dig a little deeper.